# Asus laptop power management

Tags: 12.04, laptop, power-management, battery

I have a couple of symptoms that make me think Ubuntu has some problems identifying all the components of my laptop (Asus N56VJ-S4051H).

1. When starting the computer from the OFF status, the fan goes to full speed just after the boot manager (EFI) chose the OS. The fan stays on!
2. The battery symbol in the task bar doesn't seem to recognize the battery reliably, esp. when AC power is connected as well.
3. The battery indicator starts blinking once on battery and stays on.
4. The battery is not being charged while the Ubuntu is running.

I didn't have these problems with Windows 8.

I had to switch to a Linux system after Windows 8 got on my nerves too much...

Could you please help me solve these issues or point me to a direction where I can find further information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your laptop affected this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/upower/+bug/1088146

Installing saucy kernel (3.11.x) make that symptoms happen less frequent, according to my experience.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-saucy
```

Comment: I can confirm what you said. Thank you!!! On the other hand I was not successful to try the acpi command, probably because I don't know how to use Emacs...

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't comment to ask for clarification due tp lack of rep points, I'll attempt to answer your question as best I can:

Does this also happen when you boot off the live CD / usb stick?

In either case it might be worth looking at your grub boot options and trying to match them with your bios.

At the Grub2 boot loader screen choose the kernel you want to boot and press 'e'

go to the end of the line and add / edit the line:

```
acpi=on
```

If that doesn't work, please tell us what model Asus you have, and what UFEI version you are running if possible.